# How to extract all values from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract, key-value

I have a dictionary `d = {1:-0.3246, 2:-0.9185, 3:-3985, ...}`.

How do I extract all of the values of `d` into a list `l`?

Answer (score 447, accepted):

If you only need the dictionary keys `1`, `2`, and `3` use: `your_dict.keys()`.

If you only need the dictionary values `-0.3246`, `-0.9185`, and `-3985` use: `your_dict.values()`.

If you want both keys and values use: `your_dict.items()` which returns a list of tuples `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2), ...]`.

Comment: If you are using Python 3 you'll want to use `list(your_dict.values())` to get a list (and not a dict_values object).

Answer (score 69):

Use `values()`

```
>>> d = {1:-0.3246, 2:-0.9185, 3:-3985}

>>> d.values()
<<< [-0.3246, -0.9185, -3985]
```

Answer (score 64):

For Python 3, you need:

```
list_of_dict_values = list(dict_name.values())
```

Comment: Thank You for mentioning that method `list()` is needed

Comment: this is mandatory for accessing the elements using indices

Comment: Actually, ```dict_name.values().tolist``` should be faster if you are having 1d Array, check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890735/difference-between-listnumpy-array-and-numpy-array-tolist#answer-27891227)

Comment: @hozayfa-el-rifai That's for numpy only. `{}.values().tolist()` doesn't work.

Comment: @TedBrownlow not sure what i was trying to prove here, but yeah you are right!

Answer (score 17):

Call the `values()` method on the dict.

Answer (score 17):

If you want all of the values, use this:

```
dict_name_goes_here.values()
```

If you want all of the keys, use this:

```
dict_name_goes_here.keys()
```

IF you want all of the items (both keys and values), I would use this:

```
dict_name_goes_here.items()
```

Answer (score 17):

For nested dicts, lists of dicts, and dicts of listed dicts, ... you can use

```
from typing import Iterable

def get_all_values(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for v in d.values():
            yield from get_all_values(v)
    elif isinstance(d, Iterable) and not isinstance(d, str): # or list, set, ... only
        for v in d:
            yield from get_all_values(v)
    else:
        yield d
```

An example:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': [3, 4]}, 'e': [{'f': 5}, {'g': set([6, 7])}], 'f': 'string'}
list(get_all_values(d)) # returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'string']
```

Big thanks to @vicent for pointing out that strings are also `Iterable`! I updated my answer accordingly.

PS: Yes, I love `yield`. ;-)

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Note that strings are also iterable. In my use case the values in my dictionary were also string so I would run into an error about recursive depth reached. To fix, I did

```
def get_all_values(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for v in d.values():
            yield from get_all_values(v)
    elif isinstance(d, typing.Iterable) and not isinstance(d, str): # or list, set, ... only
        for v in d:
            yield from get_all_values(v)
    else:
        yield d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that issue. You are completely right! I updated my answer!

Answer (score 8):

I know this question been asked years ago but its quite relevant even today.

```
>>> d = {1:-0.3246, 2:-0.9185, 3:-3985}
>>> l = list(d.values())
>>> l
[-0.3246, -0.9185, -3985]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want all of the values, use this:

```
dict_name_goes_here.values()
```

Answer (score 5):

Code of python file containing dictionary

```
dict={"Car":"Lamborghini","Mobile":"iPhone"}
print(dict)
```

If you want to print only values (instead of key) then you can use :

```
dict={"Car":"Lamborghini","Mobile":"iPhone"}
for thevalue in dict.values():
    print(thevalue)
```

This will print only values instead of key from dictionary

**Bonus :**  If there is a dictionary in which values are stored in list and if you want to print values only on new line , then you can use :

```
dict={"Car":["Lamborghini","BMW","Mercedes"],"Mobile":["Iphone","OnePlus","Samsung"]}
nd = [value[i] for value in dict.values()
         for i in range(2)]
print(*nd,sep="\n")
```

Reference - [Narendra Dwivedi - Extract Only Values From Dictionary](https://www.narendradwivedi.org/2022/01/python-extract-only-value-from-dictionary.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
d = <dict>
values = d.values()
```

Answer (score 3):

To see the keys:

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
```

To get the values that each key is referencing:

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(d[key])
```

Add to a list:

```
for key in d.keys():
    mylist.append(d[key])
```

Comment: list comprehension can help as well

Comment: list=[d[key] for key in d.keys()]

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic duck-typing should in principle determine what an object can do, i.e., its properties and methods. By looking at a dictionary object one may try to guess it has at least one of the following: `dict.keys()` or `dict.values()` methods. You should try to use this approach for future work with programming languages whose type checking occurs at runtime, especially those with the duck-typing nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary_name={key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3}
dictionary_name.values()
```

Comment: as pointed in the answer by Faaiz Qadri, you need to wrap you solution inside `list()` otherwise it returns `dict_values`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `items()`, `keys()` and `values()` to get both the keys and values, only the keys and only the values in a dictionary respectively as shown below:

```py
person = {'name':'John', 'age':35, 'gender':'Male'}

print(person.items()) # dict_items([('name', 'John'), ('age', 35)])
print(person.keys()) # dict_keys(['name', 'age'])
print(person.values()) # dict_values(['John', 35])
```

And, you can iterate `items()`, `keys()` and `values()` with `for` loop as shown below:

```py
person = {'name':'John', 'age':35}

for key, value in person.items(): # name John
    print(key, value)             # age 35
    
for key in person.keys(): # name
    print(key)            # age
    
for value in person.values(): # John
    print(value)              # 35
```

But, you cannot access `items()`, `keys()` and `values()` with `[]` as shown below because there are errors:

```py
person = {'name':'John', 'age':35}

print(person.items()[0]) # Error
print(person.keys()[0]) # Error
print(person.values()[0]) # Error
```

But, if using [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), you can access them with `[]` as shown below:

```py
person = {'name':'John', 'age':35}

print(list(person.items())[0]) # ('name', 'John')
print(list(person.keys())[0]) # name
print(list(person.values())[0]) # John
```

Answer (score -1):

Normal Dict.values()

will return something like this

dict_values(['value1'])

dict_values(['value2'])

If you want only Values use

- Use this

**list(Dict.values())[0]** # Under the List