# Accessing the values of a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
Data = {
    "weight_factors" : {
        "parameter1" : 10,
        "parameter2" : 30,
        "parameter3" : 30
        },
    "other_info" : {
        }
}
```

I want to get the sum of all values that are under the key `"weight_factors"`:

```
sum = Data["weight_factors"]["parameter1"] + 
      Data["weight_factors"]["parameter2"] + 
      Data["weight_factors"]["parameter3"]
```

Currently, in order to avoid entering `Data["weight_factors"]` repeatedly, I use the following commands:

```
d = Data["weight_factors"]
d["parameter1"] + d["parameter2"] + d["parameter3"]
```

But, I guess there should be an operator that does the same thing, without storing `Data["weight_factors"]` as an intermediate variable. I was wondering if such a command or an operator exists.

```
Data["weight_factors"]<unknown operator>(["parameter1"] + 
                                         ["parameter2"] +
                                          ... 
                                         ["parametern"])<unknown operator>
```

**EDIT:**
In the example given above, it was just a sum operation. But it could for example be:

```
Data["weight_factors"]["parameter1"] * Data["weight_factors"]["parameter2"] + Data[‌​"weight_factors"]["parameter3"]
```

But I do not want enter `Data["weight_factors"]` repeatedly. That's the thing I am searching for... I don't know whether such an operator exists. (In MATLAB, there exists such a thing for cell structures).

Comment: I found the answer of @iCodez better; I don't have to import a module... I will probably implement by using `'.itervalues()'`.

Comment: Oh, so you're just asking how do you get the values from a dict? Someone might flag this as a repeat question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PYTHON how to extract all of the values from a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/python-how-to-extract-all-of-the-values-from-a-dictionary)

Comment: As I have written in my question, I'm searching for the `<unknown operator>` but I couldn't find anything similar or relevant. Therefore, I needed to ask it as a new question. Even at giving a title to my question, I was unsure about how to state it (can be checked through my edit history)...

Comment: @AaronHall, for example in the example given above, it was just a sum operation. But it could for example be: `Data["weight_factors"]["parameter1"]*Data["weight_factors"]["parameter2"]+Data["weight_factors"]["parameter3"]`. But I do not want enter `Data["weight_factors"]` repeatedly. That's the thing I am searching for.

Comment: I'm thinking you should just continue to use assignment like you were doing then. And now you know how to access a dict values, which you could also assign to something. But the question itself is a duplicate as far as I can tell. If others agree, it will be closed. No big deal.

Comment: @AaronHall I haven't learned how to access the values of dict from that answer. But for my specific case, it remembered me that I could use it. I am just searching for an operator. But I don't know if such an operator even exists...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that kind of operator does not exist for the [built-in dict type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

I suppose you *could* make your own dict type that inherited from [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and overloaded an operator:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __add__(self, other):
        """Overload the + operator."""
...
```

but that is somewhat inefficient and not very good for readability.

If you just want to sum the values, you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) ([`dict.itervalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) if you are using Python 2.x):

```
>>> Data = {
... "weight_factors" : {
...     "parameter1" : 10,
...     "parameter2" : 30,
...     "parameter3" : 30
...     },
... "other_info" : {
...     }
... }
>>> sum(Data["weight_factors"].values())
70
>>>
```

Otherwise, I would just use what you have now:

```
d = Data["weight_factors"]
myvar = d["parameter1"] * d["parameter2"] + d["parameter3"]
```

It is about as clean and efficient as you can get.

Comment: Right, I could use sum() and .values(). Thanks for your response. But I am actually searching for a general solution. If none exists, I would definitely use your suggestion!

Comment: I think you're going to need to be more specific about what kind of "general solution" you're after; iCodez's answer exactly addresses the question I thought you were asking, anyway.

Comment: @DSM I am actually searching for an 'unknown operator', which I have stated in my question. But I don't know whether such an operator exists...

Comment: @iCodez I guess that's the true answer of my question, or more precisely: the answer I was searching for. I don't know whether accepting your reply leads to misunderstanding of some aggressive users and some other readers. Maybe you have to edit your reply a little bit ;)

Comment: @T-1000 - I'll incorporate my comment into my answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution to repeatedly get the same item from a mapping or index, I suggest the `operator` module's `itemgetter`:

```
>>> import operator

>>> Data = {
    "weight_factors" : {
        "parameter1" : 10,
        "parameter2" : 30,
        "parameter3" : 30
        },
    "other_info" : {
        }
    }
```

Now create our easy getter:

```
>>> get = operator.itemgetter('weight_factors')
```

And call it on the object whenever you want your sub-dict:

```
>>> get(Data)['parameter1']
```

returns:

```
10
```

and

```
>>> sum(get(Data).values())
```

returns

```
70
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just "how do I access a dict's values easily and repeatedly?" you should just assign them like this, and you can reuse them again and again.

In Python 2:

```
vals = Data['weight_factors'].values()
```

In Python 3, values returns an iterator, which you can't reuse, so materialize it in a list:

```
vals = list(Data['weight_factors'].values())
```

and then you can do whatever you want with it:

```
sum(vals)
max(vals)
min(vals)
```

etc...