# Difference between list(numpy_array) and numpy_array.tolist()

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

What is the difference between applying `list()` on a `numpy` array vs. calling `tolist()`?

I was checking the types of both outputs and they both show that what I'm getting as a result is a `list`, however, the outputs don't look exactly the same. Is it because that `list()` is not a `numpy`-specific method (i.e. could be applied on any sequence) and `tolist()` *is* `numpy`-specific, and just in this case they are returning the same thing?

Input:

```
points = numpy.random.random((5,2))
print "Points type: " + str(type(points))
```

Output:

```
Points type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Input:

```
points_list = list(points)
print points_list
print "Points_list type: " + str(type(points_list))
```

Output:

```
[array([ 0.15920058,  0.60861985]), array([ 0.77414769,  0.15181626]), array([ 0.99826806,  0.96183059]), array([ 0.61830768,  0.20023207]), array([ 0.28422605,  0.94669097])]
Points_list type: 'type 'list''
```

Input:

```
points_list_alt = points.tolist()
print points_list_alt
print "Points_list_alt type: " + str(type(points_list_alt))
```

Output:

```
[[0.15920057939342847, 0.6086198537462152], [0.7741476852713319, 0.15181626186774055], [0.9982680580550761, 0.9618305944859845], [0.6183076760274226, 0.20023206937408744], [0.28422604852159594, 0.9466909685812506]]

Points_list_alt type: 'type 'list''
```

Comment: One is a list of lists, the other a list of `numpy` arrays -- because `.tolist` "walks down the tree" and correctly makes every level into lists, while `list(...)` just "walks" the top level.  So, what **is** the question...?

Comment: There is no need for this statement at all: print "Points type: " + str(type(points)), you can check the type of the variable by using type(varName_here)  i.e., type(points)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your example **already shows the difference**; consider the following 2D array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> a.tolist()
[[0, 1], [2, 3]] # nested vanilla lists
>>> list(a)
[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3])] # list of arrays
```

[`tolist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) handles the full conversion to nested vanilla lists (i.e. `list` of `list` of `int`), whereas `list` just iterates over the first dimension of the array, creating a list of arrays (`list` of `np.array` of `np.int64`). Although both are lists:

```
>>> type(list(a))
<type 'list'>
>>> type(a.tolist())
<type 'list'>
```

the *elements* of each list have a different type:

```
>>> type(list(a)[0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(a.tolist()[0])
<type 'list'>
```

The other difference, as you note, is that `list` will work on any iterable, whereas `tolist` can only be called on objects that specifically implement that method.

Answer (score 2):

`.tolist()` appears to convert all of the values recursively to python primitives (`list`), whereas `list` creates a python list from an iterable.  Since the numpy array is an array of `arrays`, `list(...)` creates a `list` of `array`s

You can think of `list` as a function that looks like this:

```
# Not the actually implementation, just for demo purposes
def  list(iterable):
    newlist = []
    for obj in iter(iterable):
        newlist.append(obj)
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that `tolist` recursively converts all data to python standard library types.

For instance:

```
>>> arr = numpy.arange(2)
>>> [type(item) for item in list(arr)]
[numpy.int64, numpy.int64]
>>> [type(item) for item in arr.tolist()]
[builtins.int, builtins.int]
```

Aside from the functional differences `tolist` will generally be quicker as it knows it has a numpy array and access to the backing array. Whereas, `list` will fall back to using an iterator to add all the elements.

```
In [2]: arr = numpy.arange(1000)

In [3]: %timeit arr.tolist()
10000 loops, best of 3: 33 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit list(arr)
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.7 µs per loop
```

I would expect the `tolist` to be

Answer (score 0):

Additional differences:

1. If you have a 1D numpy array and convert it to a list by using `tolist()` *that will change numpy scalar to the nearest compatible built-in python type.* On the contrary, list() does not, it keeps the type of numpy scalar as it is.

```
# list(...)

a = np.uint32([1, 2])

a_list = list(a)   # [1, 2]

type(a_list[0])    # <class 'numpy.uint32'> 


# .tolist()

a_tolist = a.tolist()  # [1, 2]
      
type(a_tolist[0])   # <class 'int'>
```

2. If the numpy array with a scalar value meaning 0D array, using list() will throw an error but tolist() will only convert it as python scalar without any errors.

```
a = np.array(5)

list(a) # TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

a.tolist() # 5
```