# What are the differences from list(df['column']) and df['column'].to_list()?

Tags: python, pandas, list

When I want a list from a DataFrame column (`pandas 1.0.1`), I can do:

```
 df['column'].to_list()
```

or I can use:

```
list(df['column'])
```

The two alternatives works well, but what are the differences between them?
Is one method better than the other?

Comment: `list()` is a built-in Python function, whereas `df.to_list()` is a DataFrame convenience function.  Run some `%%timeit` benchmarks in your IDE to see if one runs faster than the other.

Comment: mostly this is of use for `numpy arrays`. Try: `a = np.array(1)` -> `list(a)` will give you an error, while `a.tolist()` will return a scalar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`list` receives an iterable and returns a pure python list. It is a built-in python way to convert *any* iterable into a pure python list.

`to_list` is a method from the core pandas object classes which converts their objects to pure python `lists`. The difference is that the implementation is done by pandas core developers, which may optimize the process according to their understanding, and/or add extra functionalities in the conversion that a pure `list(....)` wouldn't do.

For example, [the `source_code` for this piece is:](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/core/base.py#L1010-L1031)

```
def tolist(self):
    '''(...)
    '''
    if self.dtype.kind in ["m", "M"]:
        return [com.maybe_box_datetimelike(x) for x in self._values]
    elif is_extension_array_dtype(self._values):
        return list(self._values)
    else:
        return self._values.tolist()
```

Which basically means `to_list` will likely end up using either a normal list comprehension - analogous to `list(...)` but enforcing that the final objects are of panda's `datetime` type instead of python's datetime -; a straight pure `list(...)` conversion; or using `numpy`'s `tolist()` implementation.

The [differences between the latter and python's `list(...)` can be found `in this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890735/difference-between-listnumpy-array-and-numpy-array-tolist).