# What happened to the python binding for the color parameter in OpenCV's draw rectangle (cv2.rectangle)?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

This used to work:

```
cv2.rectangle(image, (top,left), (bottom,right), color=color_tuple, thickness=2)
```

where image is a nxmx3 array of np.uint8 values and color_tuple consisted of a 3 tuple of np.uint8 values, e.g. (2,56,135).  Now it produces this error raised in my own code (not the Numpy or OpenCV code):

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Argument given by name ('color') and position (3)
```

Removing the names from the arguments:

```
cv2.rectangle(image, (top,left), (bottom,right), color_tuple, 2)
```

Produces this error:

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I believe both errors are related to the overridden rectangle function in openCV's source code where it looks for an image followed by a pair of tuples.  If it can't find it, it tries to use an overridden function that accepts an image and a rectangle tuple.   So the traceback is not representative of the error, but I can't figure out why the numpy types aren't accepted anymore.  I tried np.int16, int (which casts it as a np.int64).  I could only get it to run by casting the array as python native ints with the tolist() function.

```
color_tuple = tuple(np.array(np.random.random(size=3)*255, dtype=np.int).tolist())
```

What caused this?  Are there other places OpenCV where numpy datatypes don't work?

```
Python: 3.6.9
OpenCV: 4.5.1
Numpy: 1.19.5
IDE: VSCode
```

Comment: try `np.int8`. OpenCV uses either float or `uint8` type for images

Comment: In what version do you think it used to work? From the docs at https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9 as far back as 3.0.0, it was never `color=`. It was always just a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types) post, using `tolist()` is probably the right solution.

The issue is that the type of the elements of `color_tuple` is `<class 'numpy.int32'>`.
`cv2.rectangle` expects **native** python type - tuple with elements of type `int`.

Here is a code sample that reproduces the error:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.uint8)  # Create mat with type uint8 

top, left, bottom, right = 10, 10, 100, 100

color_tuple = tuple(np.array(np.random.random(size=3)*255, dtype=np.int))

print(type(color_tuple[0]))  # <class 'numpy.int32'>

cv2.rectangle(image, (top, left), (bottom, right), color=color_tuple, thickness=2)
```

The above code prints `<class 'numpy.int32'>` and raises an exception:

> Argument given by name ('color') and position (3)

The same code with `.tolist()`:

```
color_tuple = tuple(np.array(np.random.random(size=3)*255, dtype=np.int).tolist())

print(type(color_tuple[0]))
```

The above code prints `<class 'int'>` without exceptions.

---

Apparently `.tolist()` converts the type to native `int` (NumPy array class implements the method `.tolist()` to do so).

- `l = list(np.array((1, 2, 3), np.int))` returns a list of `numpy.int32` elements.
- `l = np.array((1, 2, 3), np.int).tolist()` returns a list of `int` elements.

The difference of `list` and `tolist()` is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890735/difference-between-listnumpy-array-and-numpy-array-tolist).

Comment: cv2.rectangle(image, (top,left), (bottom,right), color=color_tuple.tolist(), thickness=2)