# How to check for `list(np.ndarray)` in Python code?

Tags: python, numpy, abstract-syntax-tree

Looking at this [Difference between list(numpy_array) and numpy_array.tolist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890735/difference-between-listnumpy-array-and-numpy-array-tolist) got me interested in this question. While I don't think that calling `list` on a numpy array is necessarily a problem, it is often not what I would prefer compared to using the `np.ndarray.tolist` method.

Just using something like grep for `list` would return far too many results in some projects. But for some input `x` it is difficult for me to think of any generally-applicable regex for it.

So instead I am wondering if there is some other way to search the code for calling a list on a numpy array. My best guess is to use the ast library, but I am not familiar with it.

Ideally I would like some kind of function.

```py
import ast


def is_list_on_arr(code):
    '''Indicate if list called on numpy array.'''
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    code = """
    import numpy as np
    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    lst = list(arr)
    """
    is_list_on_arr(code)
```

How can I check if a code base contains such a pattern?

Comment: Unless your IDE has a check for this, I don't think it will be easy to do. Figuring out data flow and the types of parameters is complex.

Comment: Unless you were in the habit of using `list` like this, you probably won't find many cases.  More likely you might have hidden instances, such as list comprehension, `[i for i in an_array]` or the equivalent `for loop`.