# how can i print the elements of a dictionary without the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried something like this :

```
for key in dict_of_ims:
    for element in key:
        print(element)
```

it just gave the keys letter by letter

Comment: `for v in dict_of_ims.values(): print v ` ?

Comment: You can use print(list(dict_of_ims.values())) to get a list of values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract all values from a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/how-can-i-extract-all-values-from-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all the values of a list which is value for each key in a dictionary:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    for ele in value:
        print(ele)
```

Example:

```
dict1 = {'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50], 'name': ['hari']}
```

Output:

`gallons`

`5`

`10`

`50`

`hari`

Comment: And if you code in Eclipse, you can hide warning: for _, value in dict_of_ims.items():

Comment: maybe my question wasn't accurate, my keys has lists i want each element of each list in each key to be printed seperately not an entire list at once.

Comment: Thanks @lara. understood the question now. I will update it

Comment: @lara Now please check and confirm me Is this you are expecting ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `values`:

```
print(dict_of_ims.values())
```

Or to unpack the values:

```
for val in dict_of_ims.values():
    for item in val:
        print(item)
```

Comment: maybe my question wasn't accurate, my keys has lists i want each element of each list in each key to be printed seperately not an entire list at once.

Comment: @lara, this is why you should try to share reproducible code along with example and expected output

Comment: kindly note this will print only letters of key names

Comment: No it prints values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in dict_of_ims:
    print(dict_of_ims[key])
```

Comment: maybe my question wasn't accurate, my keys has lists i want each element of each list in each key to be printed seperately not an entire list at once.

Answer (score 0):

In dict values method is there 
`print(dict_of_ims.values())` will return list of values 
`print(dict_of_ims.keys())` will return list of keys

Comment: maybe my question wasn't accurate, my keys has lists i want each element of each list in each key to be printed seperately not an entire list at once.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on other answers, your dictionary will look something like this:

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Now you can use `chain` from `itertools` to get your desired output:

```
from itertools import chain
values = list(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
print(values)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can further, format it based on your requirement:

```
>>> print(" ".join(values))
1 2 3 4 7 8 9
>>> print("\n".join(values))
1
2
3
4
7
8
9
```