# Get all field names for dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to get all nested field names of Python dictionary?

For example:

Dictionary:

```
{
   "a": [
      {
         "b": {
            "c": [
               "f",
               "g"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Result:

```
'a[0].b.c[0]'
'a[0].b.c[1]'
```

Comment: You want the names of the fields or their index in the respective dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract all values from a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/how-can-i-extract-all-values-from-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @r.uckus no, it's not the same

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to do it, but a simple recursive function should be able to traverse an arbitrarily deep dict or even a mixture of dicts and lists. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys

Comment: your output be like that? : `a` `b` `c`

Comment: @DevanshuMisra output example is in a result

Comment: Shouldn't the first output be `a[0]["b"]["c"][0]`?

Comment: I think your use case is not generic. Hence you'll have to write your own code for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def traverse(d, c = []):
  if isinstance(d, list):
    for i, a in enumerate(d):
      if not isinstance(a, (dict, list)):
        yield '.'.join(c+[f'[{i}]'])
      else:
        yield from traverse(a, c+[f'[{i}]'])
  elif isinstance(d, dict):
     for a, b in d.items():
        if not isinstance(b, (list, dict)):
           yield '.'.join(c+[a])
        else:
           yield from traverse(b, c+[a])


d = {'a': [{'b': {'c': ['f', 'g']}}]}
import re
print([re.sub('\.(?=\[)', '', i) for i in traverse(d)])
```

Output:

```
['a[0].b.c[0]', 'a[0].b.c[1]']
```