# Convert dictionary to array in Python 3

Tags: python

I have the following **dictionary**:

```
{
'0':'test1'
'1':'test2'
'2':'test3'
'3':'test4'
}
```

I want to **convert** it into an **array** in which the **keys**, as you can notice, are the **indexes**, and the **key values** are the **values**.
So, basically, I want `['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']`.

There is [another question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/how-can-i-extract-all-values-from-a-dictionary-in-python), which I read, but it ***doesn't*** solve my question, since I want the keys of the **dictionary** as **indices**.

Comment: What if the keys are, for example, 1-2-5-7? How big should the resulting array be?

Answer (score 2):

if the dictionary is named `d`, do `list(d.values())`.

If you know the keys are the numbers 0-N, and you'd like the resulting array to be in that order, do:

```
[x[1] for x in sorted(d.items())]
```

Comment: That will be in arbitrary order, while OP wants to use the keys as the list indices.

Comment: @interjay. I didn't read the question that way initially, but you may be right. In any case, edited my answer.