# How to read a column of datatype json and convert into list using Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a text file with two columns in Pandas. One of the column datatypes is JSON. I want to convert this column into a list of lists or just a list.

Input:

```
bank    time
ABC     {"Monday":[["9:00","18:00"]],"Tuesday":[["9:00","18:00"]]}
```

Expected Output:

```
bank    time
ABC     [[Monday, 9:00, 18:00], [Tuesday, 9:00, 18:00]]
```

I tried the following code but getting an error:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df1 = pd.read_csv('n.txt',sep = '\t')
a = df1['time']
df1['time']  = json.loads(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the json string with `json.loads()` but it needs to be done on each row separetly. This can be done by using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Then, you can convert the obtained dictinary to your wanted output. It can be done as follows:

```py
def convert_json(row):
    return [[k] + v[0] for k,v in json.loads(row).items()]
    
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(convert_json)
```

Result:

```
    bank                                               time
0    ABC    [[Monday, 9:00, 18:00], [Tuesday, 9:00, 18:00]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. I have a small doubt for return statement. My analysis is >  k=Day, v= first item of list, am i right ? Also what is > ".items() "

Comment: @Anonymus: Happy to help. `json.loads(row)` will return a dictionary and `.items()` will loop over the entries, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/how-can-i-extract-all-values-from-a-dictionary-in-python). `v` is the value of the dictionary which in this case is e.g. `[["9:00","18:00"]]`. This is a list of lists with one entry, using `v[0]` we can get it as a single list `["9:00","18:00"]`. `[k] + v[0]` will then add these two together to get `[Monday, 9:00, 18:00]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `List Comprehension` with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [2020]: def myfunc(row):
      ...:     return [[k] + v[0] for k,v in row.items()]
      ...:

In [2022]: df['time'] = df['time'].apply(myfunc)

In [2023]: df
Out[2023]: 
  bank                                             time
0  ABC  [[Monday, 9:00, 18:00], [Tuesday, 9:00, 18:00]]
```