# how to find the value of dictionary which have more 2 key and value

Tags: python

i have a list of dictionary as below:

```
benefits = [{'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'abcxyz'}, {'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'qwerty'}]
```

i would like to get a value of 'BENEFITS' if the value of 'name of benefits' = 'abcxyz'.. Could you please assist on this ?

```
for i in benefits:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if v == "abcxyz":
            print(v)
```

the expected output is `if v == "abcxyz"` , output is 'DEATH'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract all values from a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/how-can-i-extract-all-values-from-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `for` loop there. Just grab the items directly:

```
for d in benefits: 
    if d["name of benefits"] == "abcxyz":
        print(d["BENEFITS"])
```

Note that if you just check if `v=="abcxyz"`, it will check *any* value is `"abcxyz"`, regardless of any key.

Comment: thank you  so much Chris, This is what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
benefits = [{'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'abcxyz'}, {'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'qwerty'}]
for i in benefits:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if v == "abcxyz":
            print(i['BENEFITS'])
```

Output:

```
DEATH
```

What you did wrong is that you printed `v` if `v == "abcxyz"`. You need to print the value of `BENEFITS` instead which is what I changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just expand a list comprehension into `print` and specify `sep` and `end` arguments to `print`.

```
benefits = [{'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'abcxyz'},
            {'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'qwerty'}]

print(*[d['BENEFITS'] for d in benefits if d['name of benefits'] == 'abcxyz'], sep=',', end='\n')
```

This cleanly handles the possibility of multiple dictionaries in the `benefits` list having the required `'name of benefits'` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the one line below.

```py
mylist = [d['BENEFITS'] for d in benefits if d['name of benefits'] == 'abcxyz']
```

Note that it will give you a list of strings (even if there is only one string).

Example:

```py
benefits = [{'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'abcxyz'}, {'BENEFITS': 'DEATH', 'name of benefits': 'qwerty'},
            {'BENEFITS': 'LIFE', 'name of benefits': 'abcxyz'}]
mylist = [d['BENEFITS'] for d in benefits if d['name of benefits'] == 'abcxyz']
print(mylist)
# This will give you: ['DEATH', 'LIFE']
```