# Get value from key within nested Lists of Dicts

Tags: python, json

I am fairly new to Python and have been working on trying to print out the values attached to a key which is present in a nested list of dictionaries in a JSON. Here is the structure from what I can tell:

> details - List of dicts
>
> > scorecardDetails - List of dicts
> >
> > > scorecard - Dict
> > >
> > > > playerHandicap - Key:Value

It is also worth noting there is another list called 'summary' at the same level as 'details'.

This is where I am at currently, but am struggling to work out how to identify that I only want to look at the 'playerHandicap' key:

```
details_list = json_load['details']

for index in range(len(details_list)):
    for key in details_list[index]:
        print(details_list[index][key])
```

Here is a snapshot of the JSON (the key/value pair required is in the 'scorecard' dict which there is multiple of):

```
"details":[
      {
         "startTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16.000Z",
         "formattedStartTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16Z",
         "scorecardDetails":[
            {
               "scorecard":{
                  "id":172482642,
                  "customerId":"******",
                  "playerProfileId":*****,
                  "roundPlayerName":"*******",
                  "connectDisplayName":"********",
                  "courseGlobalId":21042,
                  "courseSnapshotId":43716,
                  "frontNineGlobalCourseId":21042,
                  "scoreType":"STROKE_PLAY",
                  "useHandicapScoring":true,
                  "useStrokeCounting":false,
                  "startTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16.000Z",
                  "formattedStartTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16Z",
                  "endTime":"2021-04-23T09:09:47.000Z",
                  "formattedEndTime":"2021-04-23T09:09:47Z",
                  "unitId":"1",
                  "roundType":"ALL",
                  "inProgress":false,
                  "excludeFromStats":false,
                  "holesCompleted":18,
                  "publicRound":false,
                  "score":29,
                  "playerHandicap":0,
                  "courseHandicapStr":"061018120208141604010709111517031305",
                  "teeBox":"null",
                  "handicapType":"MEN",
                  "teeBoxRating":73.03,
                  "teeBoxSlope":118,
                  "lastModifiedDt":"2021-04-23T09:09:46.000Z",
                  "sensorOnPutter":false,
                  "handicappedStrokes":101,
                  "strokes":101,
```

I'm sure it's an easy solution but struggling to get my head around the different levels of looping! Thanks :)

Comment: Note that "JSON" is a data format, and is text. When JSON data is loaded, you get native data types, not "a JSON".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Accessing Nested JSON Data](//stackoverflow.com/q/23306653/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elegant solution will be to use jmespath
Also it will also handle the cases where key doesnot exist

`pip install jmespath`

If you have `data` as correct dictionary then we can use

```
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile('details[*].scorecardDetails[*].scorecard.playerHandicap')
# this expression will look in each detail then each scorecardDetails then in each scorecard it will fetch playerHandicap
res = expression.search(data)
print(res)  # this will print the list of values from all records
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you

```
for item in json_load['details']:
    for scorecardDetail in item['scorecardDetails']:
        if 'playerHandicap' in scorecardDetail['scorecard']: 
            print(scorecardDetail['scorecard']['playerHandicap'])
```

Comment: Ah great, this kind of works. It does throw a KeyError at the the 12th result out or 51 though:
    print(scorecardDetail['scorecard']['playerHandicap'])
KeyError: 'playerHandicap'

Comment: It means the key 'playerHandicap' is not present in some of the objects. You can simply have a check. I have updated my answer with the check

Comment: +1 - was writing this exact answer when it appeared! For missing values you could also used a `try`/`except` statement to deal with `KeyError`s and have the except print "n/a". Or just add an `else:` to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question.

You can use dict.keys() to get all the keys in a dictionary.

Here is a response maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002449/19074450

```
dict_test = {"details":[
      {
         "startTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16.000Z",
         "formattedStartTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16Z",
         "scorecardDetails":[
            {
               "scorecard":{
                  "id":172482642,
                  "customerId":"6300102921355894",
                  "playerProfileId":62337607,
                  "roundPlayerName":"*******",
                  "connectDisplayName":"5536cd4a-f35e-4034-966c-a5d8238a8c26",
                  "courseGlobalId":21042,
                  "courseSnapshotId":43716,
                  "frontNineGlobalCourseId":21042,
                  "scoreType":"STROKE_PLAY",
                  "useHandicapScoring":True,
                  "useStrokeCounting":False,
                  "startTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16.000Z",
                  "formattedStartTime":"2021-03-16T12:16:16Z",
                  "endTime":"2021-04-23T09:09:47.000Z",
                  "formattedEndTime":"2021-04-23T09:09:47Z",
                  "unitId":"1",
                  "roundType":"ALL",
                  "inProgress":False,
                  "excludeFromStats":False,
                  "holesCompleted":18,
                  "publicRound":False,
                  "score":29,
                  "playerHandicap":0}}]}]}
                  
details_list = dict_test['details']

for index in details_list:
    for dict_ in details_list:
        for key_ in dict_.keys():
            print(dict_[key_])
```